# Why does loop stop after being called 63 times? It should run to the end but stops for 90 mins after 63 calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, controller, limit

I have an MVC application and I am using it to process a list folder of XML files, I have the following code:

```
Function Backlog598()

    'Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/598/"))
    Dim fileArray As FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles()
    Dim file As FileInfo
    Dim fileCounter = 0

    For Each file In fileArray

        fileCounter += 1
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim j As Integer

        'Declare Variables for Entity Creation Values
        Dim Var1 = ""
        Dim Var2 = ""
        Dim Var3 = ""
        Dim Var4 = ""
        Dim Var5 = ""
        Dim Var6 = ""
        Dim Var7 = ""

        'Declare Variable for the Message class
        Dim Message = New Message

        'Create a FileStream from the file saved in the MessagesFiles folder
        Dim fs As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/598/" + file.Name), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        xmlDoc.Load(fs)
        fs.Close()
        xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ieXMLDocument")

        'Process the Header Message
        For i = 0 To xmlNodeList.Count - 1
            For j = 0 To xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes.Count - 1
                'Set the relevant variable according to the header attributes
                Select Case xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Name
                    Case "Var1" : Var1 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                    Case "Var2" : Var2 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                    Case "Var3" : Var3 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                    Case "Var4" : Var4 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                    Case "Var5" : Var5 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                    Case "Var6" : Var6 = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                End Select
            Next
        Next

        'Set the MessageHeader attributes
        marketMessage.CreatedOn = Date.Today
        marketMessage.Var4 = DateTime.Parse(Var4)
        marketMessage.Var2 = Var2
        marketMessage.Var3 = Var3
        marketMessage.Var6 = Var6
        marketMessage.Var1 = Var1
        marketMessage.Var5 = Var5
        marketMessage.fileName = file.Name

        'Add Message class to database context
        db.Messages.Add(Message)
        Try
            db.SaveChanges()
        Catch ex As DbEntityValidationException
            System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "There were validations errors while attempting to save a Message for the xml file named : " + file.Name, EventLogEntryType.Error)
            For Each validationErrors In ex.EntityValidationErrors
                For Each validationError In validationErrors.ValidationErrors
                    System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "Message Validation Error : " + validationError.ErrorMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error)
                Next
            Next
        End Try
        Process598(xmlDoc, Message)
        System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/598/" + file.Name)

        If fileCounter = 5 Then
            Return RedirectToAction("Backlog598")
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

This code hits the controller and iterates through the folder after processing 5 files and deleting each one as they are processed the controller then is recalled as if I leave this running continually it gets very slow due to the amount of reads and so I have decided to do it like this.

This is working so far that it process 63 x 5 records for a total of 315 records but then the controller does not get hit. If I leave this running overnight then it will process another set of records. If I have 50 records per save which I have done for other smaller files then it processes 3150 before stopping.

Would this be some sort of iis or browser limit that is stopping from running through all the files?

Comment: anyone got any suggestions as to what this may be caused by?

Comment: Maybe its the 'process recycler' in IIS? BY default I believe a process will recycle (stop and start) in the middle of the night. Why are you background processing a file in a web app? Why not a service or a console app?

Comment: its just backlog of files web app for going forward just wrote a quick method to iterate folder but as I say it stops after 63 calls to itself

Comment: Can you work out if it stops due to an exception or if it stops because it thinks its finished?

Comment: There is no exception it just stops and then restarts temporarily about 90 minutes later, I tried leaving it running overnight to process backlog but can see file creation times

Comment: There's nothing in the windows event log? There will be a clue in a log somewhere and if there isn't you'll probably need to create a debug log to work out what's going on, i.e. at every line of your code write a line to a log file.

Comment: This was being caused by google chrome detecting that the page had a redirect loop although no error logs where being written in either the program or the eventvwr i had missed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome redirect loop error was causing the problem as it was detecting that this was an infinite loop

Comment: That's great that you returned and updated with your answer. How did you discover this? was it in a log somewhere?